# Amazon AWS S3 bucket permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access an S3 bucket that I don't own, but have been granted access to through access policy. The access policy says I can access with getObject, listObject anything from /* . I am guessing that allows me to access everything within the bucket. However, what is happening is that I am able to only access few files while not able to access other. 
And I suspect these files are new files in the bucket that did not exist at the time of the acl  being granted. Something is writing into that bucket with default acl. Should that be the cause of acls not taking effect and the access denied?

Comment: How are these ACLs set?

Comment: found the ans to this. The files that I was not able to access had a different owner who wasn't the owner of the bucket. The acls for the bucket only applies to the files that are owned by the bucket owner. so the way to have read access is to become a iam user within the bucket owner's root account and use that user to access the files.